# Hack Codepen's meta tags?

Tags: html, twitter, meta

***How can you bypass Codepen's pattern of overriding meta tags?***

When using html meta tags in Codepen, it looks like Codepen creates new meta tags that override the ones I created.  My tags do show up in source, but are not behaving as designed (*the context is Twitter cards*).

***Can one inject meta tags or bypass this some other way?***

https://codepen.io/RyanGarant/pen/akwgzG

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-size="large" 
data-text="Here is a super cool quote you may like! " 
data-via="Ryan_Garant" 
data-hashtags="quote" 
data-lang="en" 
data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try setting a property of `og:image`? See https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started

Comment: Hey @ArunKumar I tried this: <meta property="og:image" content="URL" /> I read the docs and it is still pulling the wrong image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you inspect the source page, you can find the meta tags you inserted but then if you scroll down a bit, you can find that Codpen overwrites your meta tags with its own. Thats why you didn't get the twitter card you expected. I have no idea how to override Codepen-injected meta tags. Now that you know the actual problem, update your question as to how one can override codepen's meta tags.